# Dependent Controls with more than 1 data series - Google Chart Tools

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm trying to create a google chart with dependency controls that will contain multiple data series. What I want to do is, in effect, generate this: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#column_chart BUT with a dependency control like here: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#dependent_controls

This is my data structure:

Year (options 2008,2009,2010,2011)
Variable (options Age Category)
Category (options 18-24,25-34,35-49,50+)
Population Proportion (options proportion1, proportion2, proportion3, proportion4)

I know I need to create arrays to be able to get this done, however, I'm not by any means a javascript person and I've gotten as far as creating ONE data series, but can't seem to find a way to be able to plot multiple data series on the same graph.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: really?....no one? :(. I'm still trying to figure this thing out and would love to actually get some data online in a user-friendly viz! Someone please help :)